# Dynamically adding properties to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, webrequest

I have a C# Windows forms application which i am using to connect to a server for making a Web Request. What i need to do is to allow the user to set certain properties via preferences and add those properties dynamically to WebRequest.

Like if i have a config file with an entry -->

```
<Properties>
        <Property name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" />
        <Property name="KeepAlive" value="true" />
</Properties>
```

Now I would like to bind the values to WebRequest Properties.

```
Uri serverURL = new Uri("http://MyServer:8080/MyPage.jsp");
        HttpWebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(serverURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(<Path of Config>);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmldoc.InnerXml);
        Dictionary<string, string> propdict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var section in xDoc.Root.Elements("Property"))
        {
            propdict.Add(section.Attribute("name").Value, section.Attribute("value").Value);
        }            

        string key = string.Empty, value = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in propdict)
        { 
             //... add the properties to wreq
        }
```

Can someone please let me know how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Sunil Jambekar

Comment: `if (name == "User-Agent") { request.UserAgent = value; }`?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to add http request headers, in which case:

```
wreq.Headers.Add(headerName, headerValue);
```

However! IIRC, many of the headers are special-cased, for example it may refuse to accept user-agent as a header, insisting instead that you set:

```
wreq.UserAgent = userAgentString;
wreq.KeepAlive = setKeepAlive;
```

So you may need:

```
foreach(var item in propdict) {
    switch(item.Name) {
        case "User-Agent":
            wreq.UserAgent = item.Value;
            break;
        case "KeepAlive":
            wreq.KeepAlive = bool.Parse(item.Value);
            break;
        // ... etc

        default:
            wreq.Headers.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

(you may want to think about case sensitivity too)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc .... That is exactly the code which i have written, however i am not happy with it. I thought if there could be something which i can apply dynamically. User-Agent and KeepAlive are not working if i do it through Headers.